# Can't use Vector from Spark ML Lib for the DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

When I'm trying to use UDF that returns the Vector object, Spark throws the following exception:

```
Cause: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported DataType: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce
```

How can I use Vector in my UDFs? The Spark version is 1.5.1.

**UPD**

```
val dataFrame: DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, 1, 2),
  (0, 3, 4),
  (0, 5, 6)
)).toDF("key", "a", "b")

val someUdf = udf {
  (a: Double, b: Double) => Vectors.dense(a, b)
}

dataFrame.groupBy(col("key"))
  .agg(someUdf(avg("a"), avg("b")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your UDF per se. It looks like you get an exception because you call it inside `agg` method on aggregate columns. To make it work you can simply push it outside `agg` step:

```scala
dataFrame
  .groupBy($"key")
  .agg(avg($"a").alias("a"), avg($"b").alias("b"))
  .select($"key", someUdf($"a", $"b"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The same code works If I change the Vectors.dense() to i.e. Array().

Comment: I know. It looks like a problem is specific to a combination of `agg` and `VectorUDT` computed columns.

Comment: Your example works for me. Thanks again. But I think this behavior is odd. The `someUdf` works well in `agg` method if I use some primitive type or i.e. `Array`. Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Problem with  `Vector` is that is not a native Spark SQL type. It is implemented as a User Defined Type (hence `VectorUDT`) with quite complex representation. I guess someone didn't predict use case like this :) Still I have to admit it is confusing.